# OOP Reusability and Maintainability

Tags: java, c++, oop

I stumble upon this situation, just think that this is happening in the industry. If i have classes like:

`Class Animal`, `Class Dog extends Animal`, `Class Crocodile extends Animal`

And then the package is closed for modification and company bought and used the package.

Later i found out that, when I have a `Class Amphibian` and `Class Mammal`, i begin to think that this classes should extend `Class Animal`, and then the `Class Dog` should not extend to `Class Animal` but rather to `Class Mammal` and also `Class Crocodile` to `Class Amphibian`.

This situation is dangerous because the company that bought and used the package can harm their programs.

So the question is:
What do programmers do when you later found out that the class is in between the hierarchy of classes which is already closed for modification?

Comment: So you're wondering how you can change a structure that was agreed upon and closed for modification. Well, you don't.

Comment: Does your personal rating of an off-site resource have any relevance to this question?

Comment: @keyser how did most companies developed their libraries or API? I mean, people aren't perfect, everything is a subject to change.

Comment: @AndyTurner it is the site where i read and then realize this question. I got the word closed modification from open closed principle from that site. i dont know its illegal.

Comment: @Paul then mention the site and that you read about OCP on it, but omit your rating.

Comment: @AndyTurner i would keep that in mind.

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-use.html Explains everything about the usage of packages.

Comment: @PaulJabines You're right. But as soon as you expose an interface to the outside world you stick to it, just look at all the mistakes in the Java API that they're not changing just to stick to the contracts they've set up. Of course, change does happen, but it's a big commitment. The general approach is to simply think carefully when developing an API.

Comment: @keyser That is what i would like to hear. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If the package is closed for modification and it does not satisfy your requirements there is not much you can do and if you have different requirements you have to write your own classes to meet them